# OOP problem while creating an app HalvingCarousel

Tags: java, oop

I have a superclass called DecrementCarousel which has a method that returns an object called CarouselRun. CarouselRun has its own methods which I need to override in HalvingCarousel, but I don't know how. DecrementCarousel:

```
public class DecrementingCarousel {
    static int [] arr ;
    static int capacity;
    int counter = 0;
    boolean alreadyExecuted = false;
    boolean alreadyRun = false;

    public DecrementingCarousel(int capacity) {
        DecrementingCarousel.capacity = capacity;
        arr = new int[capacity];

    }

    public boolean addElement(int element){
        if (alreadyExecuted) return false;
        if (counter < capacity && element > 0) {
            arr[counter] = element;
            counter++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public CarouselRun run(){
        alreadyExecuted = true;
        if (alreadyRun) return null;
        alreadyRun = true;
        return new CarouselRun();

    }


    }
```

Here are methods in CarouselRun:

```
public class CarouselRun {
    int position = 0;

    public int next() {
        int count = 0;
        while (count < arr.length && arr[position %= arr.length] <= 0) {
            position++;
            count++;
        }
        if (count == arr.length) return -1;
        return arr[position++]--;
    }

    public boolean isFinished() {
        for (int var: arr) {
            if (var > 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

How to override these CarouselRun methods in a subclass called HalvingCarousel? According to the task HalvingCarousel can only extend DecrementCarousel

Comment: Normally you would just do `HalvingCarousel extends CarouselRun` and then implement `public int next()...` and `public boolean isFinished()...`in that, possibly calling methods on CarouselRun such as `super.next()` if you want the result from that, but is that what you needed?

Comment: It is a bit strange that you set static fields in the constructor of DecrementingCarousel.

Comment: HalvingCarousel can only extend DecrementCarousel. I can't do that

Comment: If you want to override a method, you need to extends the class.

Answer (score 1):

### Inheritance

This can be done like any other simple inheritance.
You just need to declare the class HavingCarousel as a child of CarouselRun using the `extends` keyword and then use annotation `@Override` to declare that you want to override the methods of the parent class.

Parent class:

```java
public class CarouselRun {
    int position = 0;

    public int next() {
        System.out.println("Carousel run implementation of next()");
        return 1;
    }

    public boolean isFinished() {
        System.out.println("Carousel run implementation of isFinished()");
        return true;
    }

}
```

Child class:

```java
public class HalvingCarousel extends CarouselRun{
    @Override
    public int next() {
        System.out.println("HavingCarousel implementation of next()");
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFinished() {
        System.out.println("HavingCarousel implementation of isFinished()");
        return true
    }
}
```

### Interfaces

Looking at your code it could also be worth exploring interfaces instead of inheritance. Interfaces are generally more flexible and a class can implement many interfaces while it can only inherit from one parent class so interfaces should be used if there are no strong reasons opposing that like for example a huge portion of shared code which as far as I can see you will not be having.

Interface for a carousel

```java
public interface ICarousel {
    public int next();
    public boolean isFinished();
}
```

CarouselRun implements the interface:

```java
public class CarouselRun implements ICarousel {
    int position = 0;

    @Override
    public int next() {
        System.out.println("Carousel run implementation of next()");
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFinished() {
        System.out.println("Carousel run implementation of isFinished()");
        return true;
    }
}
```

HalvingCarousel implements the interface:

```java
public class HalvingCarousel implements ICarousel{
    @Override
    public int next() {
        System.out.println("HavingCarousel implementation of next()");
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFinished() {
        System.out.println("HavingCarousel implementation of isFinished()");
        return true;
    }
}
```

### Further Reading

From reading your code I believe that you still need to read more on basic Java concepts like interfaces, classes, inheritance, static vs instance attributes and modifiers. For example I can't see why you would declare your array `arr` as static but then initialize it in the constructor and then apparently you are trying to access the array `arr` in a totally unrelated instance of class `CarouselRun`. This will not work and it does not really make sense, but as these are basic concepts I cannot explain all of this here.

Comment: HalvingCarousel can only extend DecrementCarousel. I cant make it extend CarouselRun, the tests won't run

Comment: @MusicVoice Which tests? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

To override behaviour of `CarouselRun` you need a child class, overriding its' methods. Then you need to override `DecrementingCarousel.run()` in order to return the subclass of `CarouselRun`.

```
public class AnotherCarouselRun extends CarouselRun {

    @Override
    public int next() {
        //override behaviour as needed
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFinished() {
        //override behaviour as needed
        return false;
    }
}
```

Override methods in `AnotherCarouselRun` to suit your needs.

Then override behaviour of `DecrementingCatousel.run()`

```
public class HalvingCarousel extends DecrementingCarousel {

    public HalvingCarousel(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
    }

    @Override
    public CarouselRun run() {
        //do other stuff
        return new AnotherCarouselRun();
    }
}
```

`AnotherCarouselRun` **is a** `CarouselRun`, so you are abiding to the contract of `run()`. Another option is to use anonymous class:

```
public class HalvingCarousel extends DecrementingCarousel {

    public HalvingCarousel(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
    }

    @Override
    public CarouselRun run() {
        //do other stuff
        return new CarouselRun() {

            //this is anonymous class

            @Override
            public int next() {
                //override behaviour as needed
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isFinished() {
                //override behaviour as needed
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is virtually the same as first option, but you are subclassing `CarouselRun` as [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). They are mostly used when you need the class only once.

Answer (score 0):

When you realised inheritance between CarouselRun and HalvingCarouselRun you will should override methods: isFinished() and next() in class HalvingCarouselRun and add the next an realization of these methods:

```
 @Override
    public int next() {
        int beforeDecreasing;
        if (isFinished())
            return -1;

        else {
            beforeDecreasing = array[position];
            array[position] /= 2;
            do {
                position++;
                if (position == array.length) {
                    position = 0;
                }
            } while ((array[position] <= 0) && !isFinished());
        }
        return beforeDecreasing;
    }
 @Override
public boolean isFinished() {
    for (int el : array)
        if (el > 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Overrided method run in class HalvingCarousel which is inherited from DecrementingCarousel:

```
@Override
    public CarouselRun run() {
        if (!isRun) {
            isRun = true;
            return new HalvingCarouselRun();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Class Main for testing:

```
HalvingCarousel carousel = new HalvingCarousel(7);

        carousel.addElement(20);
        carousel.addElement(30);
        carousel.addElement(10);

        CarouselRun run = carousel.run();

        System.out.println(run.isFinished()); //false

        System.out.println(run.next()); //20
        System.out.println(run.next()); //30
        System.out.println(run.next()); //10
```

when we will call method run.next(), the value will be division by 2 each time, for example:

```
System.out.println(run.next()); //10
System.out.println(run.next()); //15
System.out.println(run.next()); //5
```

and so on, while value > 0, otherwise will be printed -1